# Django - CreateView with multiple models

Tags: python, django

Can I use Django [CreateViews](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView) to make a form that add data to multiple tables?
I've created a model called **UserMeta** to store some additional informations of my users.

#### The Problem

I want to create a view with CreateViews, that display fields for creating a new user ([Django User Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#user-model)) and some extra fields based on my UserMeta model:

```
class UserMeta(models.Model):
    country_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="Nome",
                            help_text="Insert the name of the country")
```

I need an output schema like this:

> |-form
>
> |-- input user.name
>
> |-- input user.username
>
> |-- input user....
>
> |-- input usermeta.country_code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`django-extra-views`](https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views/), a collection of additional CBVs, for this purpose.

```
from extra_views import CreateWithInlinesView InlineFormSet

class UserMetaInline(InlineFormSet):
    model = UserMeta    

class UpdateOrderView(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = User
    inlines = [UserMetaInline,]
```

While these inlines are generally used for foreign key relations, they work for one-to-one as well.

Comment: although it may be enough...i believe for django newbies an example with the fields on each Model will be great