# how to import django admin inlines to CreateView?

Tags: python, django

this is my CreateView

```
class PizzaCreateView(PermissionRequiredMixin,SuccessMessageMixin,CreateView,):

model = Pizza
fields = ['name','price','pizza_description','toppings','Admin.PizzaImageInline']
action = 'Add pizza'
success_url = reverse_lazy('pages:home')
permission_required = 'pizzas.add_pizza'
success_message = '"%(name)s" was created successfully'
```

this is my admin.py

```
class PizzaImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
model = PizzaImage
extra = 3

class PizzaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ PizzaImageInline, ]

admin.site.register(Pizza, PizzaAdmin)
```

how do i can transfer PizzaAdmin to my view form

Comment: So you want to ```import``` the classes or everything in the admin.py file?

Comment: no, i want to import from admin PizzaAdmin element to views for my own form

Answer (score 0):

may be use `django-extra-views` https://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views/

see below: [Django - CreateView with multiple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35560758/django-createview-with-multiple-models)